# Using an object's property in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object, advanced-custom-fields

I want to use Advanced Custom Fields to determine from which category products will be shown. The ACF field gives the ID of the category and from that I can get the slug. I can't get it to work in the array though, and so it shows all products on the page. Does anyone have suggestions or ideas why it's not working? Thanks in advance!

```
$term_id = get_field('kies_product_categorie'); //Get category id
$term = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'product_cat'); //Get terms from given category

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 9, 
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'terms' => $term->slug //Slug of given category
      )
    )
);
```

Comment: What does $term return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters), you appear to be missing the `field` attribute within the `tax_query` array.

So your $args should look like:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 9, 
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'terms' => $term->slug, //Slug of given category
        'field' => 'slug'
      )
    )
);
```